# What is the best way to periodically update mongodb database from website?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am working on a project that uses an API to obtain the members in a group for a website made with the Express framework for Node js. I would need to update the Mongodb database everyday by fetching the data with the API. What would be the best way to go about doing that as I don't want to have to manually call the API fetching.

Comment: Hi @Colin, did you get solution to your problem? Could you please explain the solution? I've similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

yo can use CronJob for that, this package could help you to fix your problem

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule